How to determine probabilities that maximize likelihood in logistic regression in case of categorical variable
Edit:
Let's say that we want to predict if mouse is Obese (Y=1) vs NotObese (Y=0) given that the predictor is the fact that a mouse has a normal Gene (X=0) vs Mutated Gene (X=1).
I can deal with this problem using logistic regression (if there is other equivalent approach in this framework i would be interested), so we can write $px=P(Y=1|X=x)=e^{a+bx}/(1+e^{a+bx})$
Here if i write $p0=P(Y=1|X=Normal Gene)=e^{a}/(1+e^{a})$ and $p1=P(Y=1|X=Mutated Gene)=e^{a+b}/(1+e^{a+b})$ i can write  that the likelihood is: $L=p0^2*(1-p0)^9*p1^7*(1-p1)^3$.
And the video give the solution: it is maximized for $p0/(1-p0)=2/9$ and $p1/(1-p1)=7/3$.
Deriving log-likelihood with respect to $p0$ (and wrt $p1$) give theses solution !
Is there other model that give the same result ?

That is a result that seem quite common as shown in Statquest video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vN5cNN2-HWE&list=PLblh5JKOoLUKxzEP5HA2d-Li7IJkHfXSe&index=2

What do you mean by "the probabilities that maximize the likelihood are given by the odds"? Odds are not probabilities, and the probabilities are not what maximize the likelihood (the coefficients in the regression are). Are you asking how to derive the maximum likelihood estimates of logistic regression coefficients for the simple case of a single binary predictor? If so, please reframe your question to be clearer.

Thank you, you are right. I edit wy question, hope it is less confused

to find the maximum, you can differentiate and set the gradient for p0/p1 to zero.  Its convenient to first take logs ( which doesn't change the location of the maximum because its a monotonic transformation)

I guess the purpose of the linked video is to show how to deal with categorical variables in logistic regression, which is fine when you need to mix categorical and continuous variables.
However, for purely categorical data, logistic regression is overkill. If you just want the probability for obesity given normal gene, simply divide the number of obese mice with the normal gene by the total number of mice with the normal gene: $p_0 = 2 / (2 + 9) = 2/11$. The same for $p_1$. This is simply estimating the probability from empirical frequencies, no different from estimating the probability of "heads" when tossing a coin.
